# How many types of DOM are there?

Tags: user-interface

How many types of DOM are there ? I know only one that is html DOM. This question was asked in an interview. Then I googled but no satisfactory result. In fact xml, sgml also have their own doms.
Please clarify.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Legacy DOM, The IE4 DOM https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-are-the-different-types-of-DOM-available-to-access-and-modify-content-in-JavaScript, in modern browsers - W3C DOM and WHATWG DOM  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction

Answer (score 0):

Types of DOM that I know of:-

- HTML DOM
- CSS DOM
- Shadow DOM
- Virtual DOM